StateFlow value is not collected in Composable - it happens only once
I have check many similar issues described here, but did not find a solution for my case.
What effect I'd like to reach:

in my Android app (Compose based) I want to observe changes of state of toggle button (which can be used in many composables),
I have a 'session' object that stores this state in shared preferences (DataStore) and this object is injectable by Dagger/Hilt: SessionCacheImpl
I want to emit new value of state of toggle button through this 'session' object every time it is changed and react on those changes in MainActivity

Value I am interesed of is collected only once when MainActivity is created
I am showing fragments of my code - just essential part related to flow. Of course I ensured myself that basic operation like buttons work. So my code is:
class SessionCacheImpl (part):
class SessionCacheImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
) : SessionCache {

private val _darkTheme = MutableStateFlow(false)
val darkTheme = _darkTheme.asStateFlow() // public one to observe in MainActivity


override suspend fun saveSession(session: Session) {
        dataStore.edit { settings ->
            settings[booleanPreferencesKey("darkTheme")] = session.darkTheme!!
        }
        _darkTheme.value = session.darkTheme!! // here I do the update with new value
    }
(...)

I've checked that session.darkTheme value is put here correctly. Method saveSession is called on toggle button click (in short words) through related viewmodel:
(...)
private fun saveSession(session: Session) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            sessionCache.saveSession(session)
        }
    }
(...)

MainActivity (part):
@Inject
    // this is instance of SessionCacheImpl
    // SessionCacheImpl object from above hidden behind an interface SessionCache
    lateinit var sessionCache: SessionCache  


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            // getDark() returns StateFlow<Boolean> object (darkTheme from SessionCacheImpl)
            val flowDarkTheme by sessionCache.getDark().collectAsState(initial = false)
            
            MemoryTheme (
                darkTheme = flowDarkTheme
            ) {
                Navigation()
            }

        }
    }
(...)

I was sure that every new value stored in my _darkTheme MutableStateFlow object will trigger update of variable flowDarkTheme in MainActivity, but it doesn't work and I think I am doing something basically wrong/I have wrong understanding how flows work. However I made this code in a same way as some tutorials show.
Maybe I forget about something?

what happens when you debug by putting a break point at val flowDarkTheme . Is your hilt dependencies set up right?

Please also show us what sessionCache.getDark() is and how it relates to the code you provided for SessionCacheImpl.

@Raghunandan Yes - DI works ok and this value is properly obtained once when MainActivity is created

@Leviathan SessionCacheImpl implements following interface
interface SessionCache which declares fun getDark(): StateFlow<Boolean>
I had this interface before and I had to add this method for consistency - because I use object behind the interface SessionCache

I updated my question with more details in code

Solution found: I had more than one instance of class -> take a look at my own answer to the question below

I found solution on my own:
Root cause of the issue wasn't bad syntax or usage of the Flows, but a fact that I had many instance of SessionCacheImpl class. I was changing value in one and trying to collect through another one. I changed the implementation of this class to be a singleton and works fine.
I investigated this by adding logs in some places in code especially focusing on value returned by $this within SessionCacheImpl object - values were different i.e. I had more than one instance.
So conclusion is to always check if we operate on proper instance of the class.
